# CakePHP bakeコマンドで作成したセレクトボックスをチェックボックスに変更したい

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephpでbakeコマンドを使ってフォームを作成しました。

その中の、複数選択可のセレクトボックスをチェックボックスに変更したいです。

ソースを見たところ、下記のコマンドでセレクトボックスが生成されているのですが、
これをチェックボックスに変えるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
$this->Form->control('courses._ids', ['options' => $courses]);
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/187658

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Form->control('courses._ids', ['options' => $courses, 'multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

選択ピッカーの作成 Form - CakePHP 3.7 Cookbook https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/views/helpers/form.html#create-select-picker

> **選択ピッカーの属性**
>   'multiple' - true をセットすると、選択ピッカー内で複数選択ができます。 'checkbox' をセットすると、複数チェックボックスが代わりに作成されます。